# How to properly handle errors for "PG::ConnectionBad could not connect to server"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My app is just a typical Rails with a Postgresql (actually, Postgres app on OS X). I would like to add exception handling when my Rails app cannot connect to the database and show plain text of connection error for now, instead of a Rails error page (or may be static HTML error page later on).

I've tried adding exception below to the `application_controller.rb`.

```
# from app/controllers/application_controllers.rb
-------------------------------------------------
  rescue_from PG::ConnectionBad, with: :database_connection_error

  def :database_connection_error
    render plain: "Could not connect to the Database"
  end

  (code ommited)
```

but it's not rendering plain text. (I also use this exception snippet on the other controllers. It's working but it's handling a different exception, e.g. I use it to handling `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error)

Is there any way to handle a `PG::ConnectionBad` or point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. I don't think you can rescue DB Connection in ApplicationController. When you get that error it happens before it reaches to your ApplicationController. So I think you should be able to do it with some kind of `MiddleWare`. Have a read on this: 'https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/understanding-rack-apps-and-middleware'.